# Given a graph $G$ with proper coloring. There is a vertex $v$ neighbor to all colors.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

For every simple graph $G$ and a proper coloring $C = \{ c_i | 1 \le i \le \chi \}$ with $\chi=\chi(G)$ colors (the minimum number of colors for a proper coloring). There is a vertex $v$  with color $c_p$ for some $p$ in $\{1, 2, \ldots, \chi\}$ such as for all colors $c_i$ with $i \ne p$ there is a  neighbor of $v$ colored with $c_i$.

Where:

$\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of a vertex in $G$.

$\chi(G)$ is the minimum number of colors for a proper vertex coloring, also known as **chromatic number**

$d(v)$ is the degree of a vertex.

There is no limits to degree of $G$.

I know that:

$\chi(G) \le \Delta(G)+1$ (1)

<s>If $d(v) = \Delta(G)$ (2) then the initial statement holds.</s> (Proven false by $S_n$).

(1) only holds for complete and odd cycles, for all other graphs we have $\Delta(G)$ as upper bound.

Seems obvious since if there is no $v$ such $d(v) = \Delta(G)$, I could use less colors to color the graph. But don't know how to work with.

Comment: By definition of $\Delta(G)$, there exists some $v$ with $d(v)=\Delta(G)$

Comment: Is $G$ allowed to be infinite? (and $\Delta(G) = \infty$?)

Comment: I don't think simple graphs can be infinite or have loops or parallel paths. Therefore no. No infinite graphs.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you're right. Therefore the proof cames directly from that? There is no declaration in the initial statement about the degree. Just about the coloring.

Comment: @Lin No, not really. A vertex of maximal degree still need not have all colours occuring (i.e., some neighbours may have different colours). In this light, I do not know what you mean by "If d(v)=Δ(G) (2) then the initial statement holds."

Comment: If there is a vertex $v$ such as the degree of $v$ is the maximum degree of the graph. This vertex nas $\Delta(G)$ neighbors, each one of them colored with a different color.  But this is false. The star graph is a good counter example. I will strike out that statement.

Comment: If $v$ is a vertex of color $c_1$, and if there is some color $c_i$ with $i\ne1$ such that $v$ has no neighbor of color $c_i$, then $v$ can be recolored with color $c_i$. If every vertex of color $c_1$ can be recolored in this way, then we can recolor all vertices of color $c_1$, and get a coloring with $\chi-1$ colors. Since this is impossible, there must be a vertex of color $c_1$ which has neighbors of every color $\ne c_1$.

Comment: “(1) only holds for complete and odd cycles, for all other graphs we have $\Delta(G)$ as upper bound” I guess you wanted to say here that “for *connected* graphs the *equality* in (1)  holds only for complete graphs and odd cycles”.